# Do I have the possibility to visit all the Schengen countries with the Visa Type D?

Tags: passports

Currently I'm in Italy for an exchange semester.  I have received a study visa for 6 months.  My passport is from Senegal.  The visa is type D, and on the visa it says that it is valid for Italy.  So, after my exams I would like to go to several Schengen countries for a small vacation.  Therefore I wonder if it's possible with the type of visa I have.

*Original text in French*:

> **Ai-je la possibilité de visiter tous les pays de l'espace schengen avec le visa type D**
>
> Au fait actuellement je me trouve en Italie pour un echange de semestre. J'ai reçu un visa d'étude de 6 mois depuis le Senegal. Le visa il est de type D, et sur le visa on a preci qu'il est valable pour Italie. Alors apres les examens je voudrais aller dans quelques pays de l'espace schengen pour passer de petites vacances. Ainsi je demandes si c'est possible avec le type de visa que j'ai.

Comment: J'ai tradui le question en Anglais, parce que cette site est en Anglais seulement / I have translated the question into English, because this site is English only.